# Android Client App with Google App Engine and GCM

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

In developing a Cloud based application, Keeping all the database in Cloud and creating a Android Client app, can we use Google App Engine and utilize it with Android? Do we need to develop in Python for GAE or in Java we can achieve it?  Please help me in getting the context, tried a lot but not clear

Comment: Voting to close, but you can develop in both python and Java, you can have a client on any platform that can use HTTP. Win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Engine backend can be written in Python, Java or Go. The following link should be helpful in getting you started with creating an App Engine connected Android app:

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-android